# Pinter's Abstract Algebra, Chapter 28, Exercise B2.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

> Prove that the set of all $(x,y,z)\in\Bbb{R}^3$ which satisfy 
>   the pair of equations $ax+by+c=0,dx+ey+f= 0$ is a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^3$.

Is there a typo, in that the pair of equations should be $ax+by+cz=0,dx+ey+fz= 0$ instead?  Otherwise, the subset is not closed with respect to scalar multiplication and therefore not a subspace.

Comment: Based on recent questions there appears to be a lot of typos in this textbook, so maybe it would be best to ask in chat first if that is suspected, since questions that boil down to a typo don't typically add much useful knowledge to the site.

Comment: Haven't tried chat, but will do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's likely there's a typo and Pinter in fact meant to include a $z$ in the last term.  Notice however, that even if they really meant the original equations (without the $z$) these could still be solved simultaneously in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  We would simply need to acknowledge the lack of dependence on $z$.  In other words, we could set this up as a linear equation:

$$
\left [ \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & 0 \\
d & e & 0 \\
\end{array} \right ] \left [ \begin{array}{c}
x\\y\\z\\
\end{array} \right ] \;\; = \;\; \left [ \begin{array}{c}
-c \\ -f \\
\end{array} \right ].
$$

This would impose constraints on $x$ and $y$, but would leave $z$ unconstrained.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of putting it is that unless $c=f=0$, in which case we have the intersection of two planes through the origin, we don't have a subspace at all.

That is, the planes must go through the origin, since every vector space contains zero.

Comment: Do you mean $c=f=0$ ?

Comment: Yeah.  @hchar. Typo.